# Trying to send js variables to a php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am trying to send js variables from my js file to another php file when the user hits "FINISH" on the main php page. Here is my code so far:

**map.php**

```
<form  action="./finalmap.php">
   <input class="finish-button" type="submit" value="FINISH" onclick="sendData();" />
</form>
```

**map.js**

```
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../finalmap.php",
        data: {
            selectedLoc: selectionArray, 
            startLoc: start,
            endLoc: end,
            dist: distance,
            locTypes: allLocations
        },
        beforeSend : function(http) { },
        success : function(response,status,http) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error : function(http,status,error) {
            $('.response').html("<span class='error'>Something went wrong</span>");
            $(".response").slideDown();
        }
    });
}
```

**finalmap.php**

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo $data;
?>
```

Post is successful and I'm able to see the contents(my code) in my finalmap.php from the alert command. When I try to console.log `$data` in finalmap.php, it is empty/null.

My goal is to send the data to finalmap.php and redirect to it.

Comment: I hope you are putting your javascripts after the php command?

Comment: try removing `action="./finalmap.php"` from your form. It seems that your are submitting the form and the send ajax request at the same time when clicking.

Comment: Also need to prevent the default browser submit process. Just removing the action won't do that. What you are currently seeing is a page reload due to the submit

Comment: I'm not sure you're on the right page about what AJAX does... "try to console.log `$data` in finalmap.php" and "redirect to it" just doesn't make sense.  Your console log would be in `map.js` and there is no redirection that should happen.

Comment: I think you guys are mistaken the problem he has it not just in the php file, but also the php variable in that file can be accessed with javascript alert function

Comment: @Dario it does refresh the page after submit. Goal is to redirect to finalmap.php once the user hits submit.

Comment: Then why do ajax?  The goal of ajax is to stay on the same page without refreshing.  If you want to redirect to another page to avoid back button refresh submits, then you don't need ajax at all.

Comment: I've tried POST and the variables still wont send.

Comment: Wait, you said "Post is successful and I'm able to see the contents(my code) in my finalmap.php from the alert command."  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you see something from `alert(response);`, then you can replace that with `console.log(response);`  You would then be able to see the content that was echoed from finalmap.php.  This would indicate that your AJAX is working exactly as it should!

Comment: does that mean that you are seeing your actual php code `<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo $data;
?>`, or the contents of `$data`?

Comment: I see this in my alert: https://imgur.com/a/0htiQtM. Everything shows besides the php code I typed in my initial question.

When I go to finalmap.php, it's blank so $data is empty when I did echo.

Comment: Where to start...  1) what data are you trying to send?  Your form has nothing to submit other than the submit button itself.  2) Your submit button should be `type='button'` rather than `type='submit'` so that ajax does the work.  3) can you explain what `data: {
            selectedLoc: selectionArray, 
            startLoc: start,
            endLoc: end,
            dist: distance,
            locTypes: allLocations
        },` is supposed to do? 4) if you type `finalmap.php` in your browser, of course there is no data.  HTTP is stateless.  As soon as it executes, the data is gone.

Comment: 1) I am trying to send an array of location names, distance (int), array of location category names, start and end names. 
2) I did that and the form doesn't go to finalmap. It stays in the same page.
3) I wanted to assign all of those variables in `data` and then submit that to finalmap.php.

Comment: Use your web console to see if the ajax request is being made, and what is being returned.  You're trying to solve a problem when you don't even know where the problem is.  You need to step back and make sure each step works:  is the button calling the ajax function?  is the ajax function sending a request? to where?  with what data?  what is the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you must reduce what you're testing to one thing at a time.  Your code has errors and is incomplete. So let's start with the errors first: If you're using AJAX, you don't want HTML to submit the form in the regular way.  If you get a page refresh, your AJAX didn't work.

```
<button type="button" id="submit-button">FINISH</button>
```

Note, no `<form>` is needed; you're submitting through AJAX.

Next, you need to be sure that your ajax function is being executed (since you're using `$.ajax`, I presume you have JQuery loaded):

```
<button type="button" id="submit-button">FINISH</button>
<script>

    // all listener functions need to wait until DOM is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // this is the same idea as your onclick="sendData();
      // but this separates the javascript from the html
      $('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
        console.log('hello world');
      });
    });
</script>
```

You use your web console to see the console.log message.

Now, try out the ajax command with a simple post:

```
<button type="button" id="submit-button">FINISH</button>
<script>

    // all listener functions need to wait until DOM is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          // "./finalmap.php" or "../finalmap.php"?
          url: "../finalmap.php",
          data: {foo: 'bar'},
          success: function(response){ 
            console.log('response is: ');
            console.log(response);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

#### finalmap.php

```
<?php echo 'This is finalmap.php';
```

If you see `This is finalmap.php` in the web console after pressing the button, then you can try sending data.

#### finalmap.php

```
<?php
    echo 'You sent the following data: ';
    print_r($_POST);
```

See where we're going with this?  The way to eat an elephant is one bite at a time.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! I have a lot to learn about .ajax and forms.

Answer (score 0):

./finalmap.php is not a thing.

Instead the code must look like this:

```
<form  action="/finalmap.php">
   <input class="finish-button" type="submit" value="FINISH" onclick="sendData();" />
</form>
```

Try using this instead.

EDIT: OOPS SORRY, I JUST CPED AND PASTED.

Comment: I don't really see what you changed from my code here.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up on that one. I was trying to remove the .